# navbar collapses on mobile with chrome/safari on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I am working on a [responsive site](http://sportsatnicolis.com.s160490.gridserver.com/dev/generic.php) with my own css not bootstrap.

On safari on the iphone and chrome on andriod the navigation is buggy.

If you open a category in the menu and try to scroll the menu will close.

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome and Safari for iphone

Comment: Its not on chrome for my android or on safari on my co workers iPhone. we cleared cache and the problem persist.

Comment: Works for me on iOS Safari (6.1.3). If its not a cache issue, perhaps it is related to particular versions of webkit? FYI: To avoid having to deal with caching false positives during web development, I would recommend turning on "Private Browsing" when using Safari and to use incognito mode when using Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed while debugging that your $(window).resize function is getting called while the user scrolls. You can simply ignore the resize event if the width has not changed and it will fix your issue.

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    if ( width == GetWidth() ) {
        return;
    }

    width = GetWidth();

    if(width >= 768){
        $("#logo").removeClass("front");
        $("#icon-bar .front").removeClass("front");
        $("#main-navi").show();
        $("#main-navi>li ul").hide();
        $("#main-navi .dropped").removeClass('dropped');
    } else {
        $("#main-navi").hide();
    }
});
```

Let me know if you run into anymore trouble!

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a mac then you could do remote debugging to see what is happening to the css on the page as you transition through the menu options.

See [How to set up remote dubugging or safari on iOS6](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/)

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple problem. A mobile device does not have a constant mouse. 
Which means hovering wont work!. Make a simple work around like:

Click once to open menu ->
Click agian to click on menu item -> and close menu

When open and user doesnt want to click on any menu item -> Click next to the menu -> close the menu

Fairly simple really, goodluck

Comment: The menu is based on click and not on hover. The problem still persist :(

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the click event on touchmove does it works?

```
function clickEvent() {
    if($("#logo").hasClass('front')){
        $("#main-navi").stop(true, true).slideToggle(250, function(){
            $("#logo").toggleClass("front");
            $("#dropdown").toggleClass("front");
        });
    } else {
        $("#main-navi").stop(true, true).slideToggle(250);
        $("#logo").toggleClass("front");
        $("#dropdown").toggleClass("front");
    }
}


$("#dropdown").on({
        click: clickEvent,

        touchmove: function() {
            $(this).off('click', clickEvent);
        },

        touchend: function() {
            $(this).on('click', clickEvent);
        }
});
```

Comment: no it was the first thing i tried doing. I figured it was some other event specific to webkit but it was my resize method.